# delta-gamma-vega VaR approximation: how to calculate the delta volatility?

Tags: black-scholes, greeks

For an option with price C, the P&L, with respect to changes of the underlying asset price S and volatility σ, is given by

P&L=δΔS+12γ(ΔS)2+νΔσ,

where δ, γ, and ν are respectively the delta, gamma, and vega greeks.

My question is: while we are able to calculate ΔS by using the spot price of underlying S and by assuming a normal distribution of its returns, what about Δσ ?

Comment: Don't approximate the P&L using Taylor expansion (i.e. delta and gamma) for VaR. The Taylor expansion is very useful for attributing the P&L when the market moves a little, but breaks down when the market moves a lot, which is exactly the risk scenarios that VaR considers.

Comment: If you do use Taylor expansion for P&L explain, then you may want to include the cross-gammas between the underlying, the implied volatility, and the time to achieve smaller unexplained P&L.

Answer (score 1):

If you use historical VaR, i.e. reprice the portfolio under many historical market move scenarios, then you need not assume anything about the distributions of the market factors. But you need distribution assumptions to use Monte Carlo simulation, rather than history.

For the underlying, you may want to assume normal or lognormal.

The implied volatility is just another market factor, observed in the market, for which you can get history. It has structure: moneyness and expiry of the option (implied volatility surface) and for some underlyings also the tenor of the underlying  (implied volatility cube). You can assume that the changes in each point of the vol surface are normally distributed, with mean 0, and, from the history, calculate the historical volatility of implied volatility, as well as the historical correlarions between the points on the vol surface.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very useful. Why do we also need to consider the historical correlations between the points on the vol surface ? Are the correlations involved in the P&L formula ? We have to consider the joint distribution of (S, vola_impl)?

Comment: I note that you edited and removed VaR. What are you trying to calculate?